# Cant use @TypeConverter to convert between LatLng and String to store in Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, android-room, android-jetpack

I'm building an android app that needs to store latitude and longitude in a room database.

Internally in my, am using the [LatLng class as part of the Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/LatLng), but need to store the longitude and latitude data in Room.

Ideally I want to save the data in a single column which is why I am using typeconvertor to convert LatLng to a String

As Room cannot store LatLng objects directly, I was hoping to use @TypeConverter to store the data as a string in the Room database.

Unfortunately Room is'nt letting me use the TypeConverter on LatLng for some reason, as shown in the error below:

**Build Failed**

> Invalid return type for a type converter. - stringToLatLng(java.lang.String)

Surely so long as I provide functions to convert LatLng to a Type that Room accepts and back again it should allow this? I have also tried returning nullable types of both string and LatLng

Thanks for your help kind internet strangers

**Database.kt**

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@Database(entities = [MyEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

**Converters.kt**

```
class Converters{

    @TypeConverter
    fun latLngToString(latLng: LatLng) : String{
        return "(${latLng.latitude},${latLng.longitude}"
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToLatLng(string: String) : LatLng{
        val s = string.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
        val list = s.split(",")
        return LatLng(list.first().toDouble(), list.last().toDouble())
    }
}
```

**MyEntity.kt**

```
@Entity
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val iD: String,
    var location: LatLng,
    val timeStamp: Long
)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the  LatLng and MyEntity classes.

Comment: Share your MyEntity class as well @olistocks98

Comment: @JinalPatel No worries, I have made the edits

Comment: @MikeT No worries I have added them in

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you need to store LatLng to String? In my case I just save it with double Latitude and Longitude.

```
@Entity(tableName = "places")
data class PlaceResponse(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "placeId")
@SerializedName("placeId")
@Expose
var placeId: Int,

@SerializedName("title")
@ColumnInfo(name = "title")
var title: String? = null,

@ColumnInfo(name = "lat")
var lat: Double = 0.0,

@ColumnInfo(name = "lng")
var lng: Double = 0.0
)
```

Comment: Only reason being is that I already use LatLng from the Maps SDK pretty consistently throughout the rest of the application, and think it would be easier to provide a TypeConverter than to change alot of the app. I definitely could change it, however I'm curious to know what I am doing wrong with my use of @Typeconverter as as far as I'm aware I'm doing everything in line with the documentation

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment in the  other answer, **your TypeConverters are fine**. I have tested them using your code as is (except that that values input are perhaps invalid). So using:-

```
    dao.insert(MyEntity("ME001", LatLng(101.12345678,202.87654321),System.currentTimeMillis()))
    dao.insert(MyEntity("ME002", LatLng(678.12345678,321.87654321),System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

and then using :-

```
    for(me: MyEntity in dao.getAllMyEntities()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","MyEntity is ${me.iD} \n\tLATITUDE is ${me.location.latitude} \n\tLONGITUDE is ${me.location.longitude} \n\tTIMESTAMP is ${me.timeStamp}")
    }
```

With getAllMyEntities being:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myentity")
fun getAllMyEntities(): List<MyEntity>
```

The resultant log produces:-

```
2022-03-18 05:32:13.279 13017-13017/a.a.so71506139kotlinroomlatlngissue D/DBINFO: MyEntity is ME001 
        LATITUDE is 90.0 
        LONGITUDE is -157.12345678999998 
        TIMESTAMP is 1647541933213
2022-03-18 05:32:13.279 13017-13017/a.a.so71506139kotlinroomlatlngissue D/DBINFO: MyEntity is ME002 
        LATITUDE is 90.0 
        LONGITUDE is -38.12345678999998 
        TIMESTAMP is 1647541933215
```

- as can be see the values input do not match the values output BUT they do match the stored values (so I assume some conversion/manipulation has been undertaken by the LatLng class).

The database, via **App Inspection** is:-

[image]

---

**HOWEVER**, when initially applying your code to an existing project I had the issue with the **invalid return type**.

What I did was to then look at using an alternative **MyLatLng** (2 doubles) and TypeConverters using:-

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

```
class MyLatLng(lat: Double, lng: Double) {

    var latitude: Double = lat
    var longitude: Double = lng

    /* <<<<<<<<<< Added AFTER successful compile >>>>>>>>>>*/
    fun getAsLatLng(): LatLng {
        return LatLng(latitude,longitude)
    }

}
```

and TypeConverters :-

```
@TypeConverter
fun myLatLngToString(latLng: MyLatLng) : String{
    return "(${latLng.latitude},${latLng.longitude}"
}

@TypeConverter
fun stringToMyLatLng(string: String) : MyLatLng{
    val s = string.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
    val list = s.split(",")
    return MyLatLng(list.first().toDouble(), list.last().toDouble())
}
```

Changing location to be a MyLatLng rather than LatLng compiled fine, so I then added the function to convert a MyLatLng to a LatLng, this then compiled fine.

I then reverted to the original LatLng and commented out the MyLatLng converters and then ***NO invalid return type*** failure.

I then created a brand new project just with your code and extras to enable it to be run. It compiled OK and ran (as the results above show).

The full code used in the new project (with the imports):-

**MyEntity**

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

@Entity
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val iD: String,
    var location: LatLng,
    val timeStamp: Long
)
```

**Converters**

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

class Converters{

    @TypeConverter
    fun latLngToString(latLng: LatLng) : String{
        return "(${latLng.latitude},${latLng.longitude}"
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToLatLng(string: String) : LatLng{
        val s = string.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
        val list = s.split(",")
        return LatLng(list.first().toDouble(), list.last().toDouble())
    }
}
```

**AllDao**

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(myEntity: MyEntity)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM myentity")
    fun getAllMyEntities(): List<MyEntity>
}
```

**TheDatabase**

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.TypeConverters

@Database(entities = [MyEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(value = [Converters::class])
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        dao.insert(MyEntity("ME001", LatLng(101.12345678,202.87654321),System.currentTimeMillis()))
        dao.insert(MyEntity("ME002", LatLng(678.12345678,321.87654321),System.currentTimeMillis()))
        for(me: MyEntity in dao.getAllMyEntities()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","MyEntity is ${me.iD} \n\tLATITUDE is ${me.location.latitude} \n\tLONGITUDE is ${me.location.longitude} \n\tTIMESTAMP is ${me.timeStamp}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same smyptoms - the compiler would not compile. For me it was an enum defined in another module. Making a copy of the enum and using this instead compiled fine. However, going back to the original enum (as you did) did not work for me.